# Sinch on emulator throws unsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, sinch

When I try to run my application on an emulator, It always crashes because Sinch throws a unsatisfiedLinkError when its trying to build the Sinch client. It also happens on some Android devices that run Lollipop. Anyone knows how to fix this?
Stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/my.little.app/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.3.0_b06e7be3fe88101ae29bdd4fd8ca9a3bc04c46cf-classes.dex"
```

Comment: What emulator are you using?

Comment: I tried on several different ones. Nexus 5 API 23, Nexus4 API 21, Nexus 5X. All using x86. All throwing the same exception. The same exception is also thrown when I install the app on "newer" phones. Honor 7 for example. I have updated Sinch! SDK to the latest version 3.9.3 .

Comment: I think I was able to fix it. The problem was that I had different 2 jnilibs folders for some reason which created this weird issue. Anyway, I removed one of them and its now working just fine!

Comment: Awesome, why dont you add the answer and I will upvote it